# Maximizing dimensions of a can with minimum cost but no given relation of cost

Tags: functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

A cylinder has a *given volume* of 1 cubic meter. *The cost of constructing top and bottom of the cyl. is twice the cost of constructing the sides*. What are the dimensions of the most economical can?

I have to find the maxima for dimensions depending on cost, but since there is no relation between ***the cost and the area***, I am lost here. It isn't working if I take cost to be x/meter square.

Ans. given : radius $= \sqrt[3]{\frac1{4\pi}}$ m, height $= \sqrt[3]{\frac{16}{\pi}}$ m

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Follow the given hint and show your work here, we'll check to it. Good work!

Comment: Substituting from the constraint, I'll get function C in one variable, and then I'll minimize it, thus finding the variable (whether R or H).
Then, I can find the other dimension from V too. I hope I'm right?Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dee Yes exactly! You should always try to put down the equations you have at disposal and see whether or not you have sufficient information to determine a solution. Don't stop for a single doubt. Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

From the givens, we have the following set up

- top and bottom area $A_1=2\pi R^2$
- lateral area $A_2=2\pi RH$
- total cost to minimize $C=2kA_1+kA_2=4k\pi R^2+2k\pi RH=2k\pi(2R^2+RH)$

with the constraint

- $V=\pi R^2H=1$